# Multi-line input in EShell

Tags: emacs, elisp, eshell

Is there a way for multi-line input in EShell?
When I want to do a quick function definition at the commandline of EShell, it doesn't really work. I tried using explicit linebreaks (\n), as well as single-quotes ('') and double quotes (""), but with no success.

When I write a newline `\n` and press enter (point is at position *) I get an error message and a new eshell prompt.

```
$ (def foo (x y ) \n *)
Symbol's function definition is void: def
```

When I use `C-q C-j` and press Enter (point is at position *) I get the same error message and a new eshell prompt.

```
$ 
(def foo (x y) *)
Symbol's function definition is void: def
```

Comment: NTEmacs 23.3.1 seems perfectly happy for me to use newlines in a function definition in eshell. What does "it doesn't really work" actually mean?

Comment: Right, that explains it. See answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to leave a parenthesis open to prevent Eshell from evaluating the input prematurely.  Also, as pointed out by phils, `def` is not defined in stock Elisp; you probably want `defun`.

Comment: Yes, that solves the problem. I use minor-modes pair (or paredit) that always give me the closing parenthesis too. When I delete it multiline input works by just pressing enter (no explizit \n in the text). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `(def)`.

In elisp you define functions with `(defun)`.

See <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> `defun` <kbd>RET</kbd>

http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Defining-Functions.html